# How to order DataFrame in python with special structure of date?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, sorting, dataframe

I have a DataFrame in python, the cell value is the purchase quantity like:

```
 code   1/18     2/18      3/18     4/18     5/18 
 1      NaN      15        15       16       14
 2      NaN      NaN       30       23       24 
 3      24       21        23       NaN      26
```

I want to order the code in terms of the date they were first purchased, the result would be:

```
code   1/18     2/18      3/18     4/18     5/18   
3      24       21        23       NaN      26
1      NaN      15        15       16       14
2      NaN      NaN       30       23       24
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need specify columns for sorting by indexing - here by all columns without first:

```
print (df.columns[1:].tolist())
['1/18', '2/18', '3/18', '4/18', '5/18']

df = df.sort_values(by=df.columns[1:].tolist())
print (df)
   code  1/18  2/18  3/18  4/18  5/18
2     3  24.0  21.0    23   NaN    26
0     1   NaN  15.0    15  16.0    14
1     2   NaN   NaN    30  23.0    24
```

If first column is `index`:

```
print (df.columns.tolist())
['1/18', '2/18', '3/18', '4/18', '5/18']

df = df.sort_values(by=df.columns.tolist())
print (df)
      1/18  2/18  3/18  4/18  5/18
code                              
3     24.0  21.0    23   NaN    26
1      NaN  15.0    15  16.0    14
2      NaN   NaN    30  23.0    24
```